# MySQL - ORM Idiorm - Prevent SQL injections

Tags: php, mysql, orm, sql-injection, idiorm

I use PHP and make my SQL calls with an ORM called [Idiorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm).

A request might look like this:

```
$person = ORM::for_table('person')->create();
$person->name = $_POST['name'];
$person->age = $_POST['age'];
$person->save();
```

It works just fine but it might not be secure against SQL injections? What is the correct / best way to solve this? Example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From their [readme](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm#readme):

> Features
>
> - Built on top of PDO.
> - Uses prepared statements throughout to protect against SQL injection attacks.

However, for the table name [it says](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm/blob/master/docs/querying.rst)

> Note that this method **does not* escape its query parameter and so
>   the table name should not be passed directly from user input.*

Same goes for limiting, ordering and grouping, so for those you need to think of alternate methods (such as letting only ascii-7 chars to pass, for example). If you need to do it, limits are just integers, so you can do [ctype_digit](http://php.net/ctype_digit) check. For ordering and grouping, you could check for alphanumerics, assuming you don't have anything else in your column names. That can be done with [ctype_alnum](http://php.net/ctype_alnum).

But the query you have there it should be fine as it doesn't have those.

Of course, you shouldn't just believe it - test it.

Comment: I voted 1 up. If I need to protect limiting, ordering and grouping, how is that done in a good way? Regexp or some PHP function made for SQL injections?

Answer (score 3):

I had a look through the source [here](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm/blob/master/idiorm.php)

And on [line 1284](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm/blob/master/idiorm.php#L1284) (part of the save() method) it appears to be preparing the statements.

So in my opinion it looks safe to assume it is already dealing with sql injection.